# android: Making multiple phone calls from android app

Tags: java, android

So, I have a list of phone contacts that I need to call in order from my app.
I call the first number, wait for it to end, then call the next one, wait and so on.

How do I modify my code so that the next contact is called only if the current call is *ended unanswered*(Missed call)?

As of now my code looks like this.

**On click listener for the Button:**

```java
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Realm db = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                RealmQuery<Contact> query = db.where(Contact.class);
                RealmResults<Contact> results= query.findAll();
                callAllContacts(results);
            }
        });
```

**callAllContacts(RealmResults):**

```java
private void callAllContacts(RealmResults<Contact> results){
        for(Contact c: results){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+c.getPhone()));
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Calling " + c.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Contact.java:**

```java
public class Contact extends RealmObject{

    public Contact() {
        name = "";
        phone = "";
    }

    @NonNull
    public String name;

    @PrimaryKey
    public String phone;

    @NonNull
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(@NonNull String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```